# Get AWS certificate name and value (ACM)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net, aws-acm

I'm trying to fetch a certificate with a status of pending in order to get CNAME value and name (to store it somewhere).
AWS .NET SDK docs says that name and value return only when certificate is ISSUED.
Is there a way to fetch name and value when status is PENDING?
by name and value I mean:
Value: _2a8e3a4906.hmhgw.acm-validations.aws.
Name: _ec12d778382.text.somedomain.com.
Thanks!

Comment: That is neither a name nor a value of a certificate. Those are the DNS validation records. They should be available using DescribeCertificate https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/describe-certificate.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeCertificate.html

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into a similar issue.
One thing to note, is to pull the data you can use the describe_certificate() method, just keep in mind that you need to sleep about 5-10 seconds until the records are generated and only then you'll get some data back.

Otherwise, they won't show up in the response.

Comment: I created a retry mechanism , without thread.sleep (it blocks the entire communication to the service)...

Comment: Hey,
I just have a celery task retry with a back-off timer on a specific Exception.
I keep on checking to see if the operation is executed, if not, i raise an exception and the task retries.

Something like this:

@app.task(
    autoretry_for=(CertNotValidated, DnsRecordsNotReady,),
    retry_backoff=30,
    retry_backoff_max=1800,
    max_retries=50)
def create_aws_dns_records:
    code_here
    if result is False:
        raise CertNotValidated
    rest of code